# Product Integral: $\lim_{\Delta x \to 0} \prod \left[f(x_i)\Delta x \right]$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis

The Volterra product integral is defined as
$$\prod_{a}^b (1+f(x)\ \mathrm{d}x)=\lim_{\Delta x \to 0} \prod \left(1+f(x_i)\Delta x\right)=\exp\left(\int_a^b f(x)\ \mathrm{d}x\right)$$

Now if I wanted to find a product integral of the form:

$$\lim_{\Delta x \to 0} \prod \left[f(x_i)\Delta x \right]$$

Would it be valid to replace $f(x)$ by $f(x)-1/dx$ in the definition of the product Volterra product integral so that:

$$\prod_{a}^b (1+(f(x)-1/\ \mathrm{d}x)\mathrm{d}x)=\prod_{a}^b [f(x)dx]$$$$=\exp\left(\int_a^b (f(x)-1/\ \mathrm{d}x)\mathrm{d}x\right)=\exp\left(\int_a^b f(x)dx-1\right)$$

Therefore, we would have:

$$\lim_{\Delta x \to 0} \prod [f(x_i)\Delta x ]=\exp\left(\int_a^b f(x) dx -1\right)?$$

If not, is there another way to evaluate a product integral of the form:

$$\lim_{\Delta x \to 0} \prod [f(x_i)\Delta x ]$$

Can it be expressed in terms of a regular integral?

EDIT:
The reason I was originally interested in this is because I believe a product integral of this type comes up if you try to find the probability that a regression function has a particular shape. Imagine you have one predictor variable, $X$, and one response variable, $Y$. For each value of $X$ you have a probability distribution over $Y$. The regression function is $E[Y_i]$. If you imagine each probability distribution as being given by a probability density function that lies above above the xy-plane then all of these density functions together would form a surface given by a function $p(x,y)$. Since to find the probability of two events happening you multiply probabilities, and if you were integrating over a curve any two successive points of any function of $X$ would come from different probability distributions, therefore to find the probability of the regression function taking the shape of a particular function it seems that you would need a product integral of the form $\prod_a^b p(x,y) ds$.

Comment: That limit, for bounded functions would be $0$: Suppose $|f(x)|\leq M$. For any  partition  $P=\{a=x_0,\ldots,b=x_n\}$ , define  $\|P\|:=\max\{x_i-x_{i-1}\}$. If the partitions are taken so that $\|P\|<\frac{1}{2M}$, you start to get very small stuff.

Comment: Yeah, I guess if $L=b-a$ and $|f(x)|<M$ then $\Delta x=L/n$ and the limit becomes $\lim_{n \to \infty} M^n L^n/n^n \to 0$